# Unable to pass a int Parameter to a Crystal Report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I have a simple Crystal Report with a single parameter, which should produce a single item on the report.   I have listed the code below, as well as the Parameter settings in the report.  When I try to print the report to the printer (The final line in the code snippet), I receive the following Exception;

CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ParameterFieldCurrentValueException was unhandled
  Message=Missing parameter values.

I have also tried the report using the ParameterFieldDefinitions and ParameterFieldDefinition objects, but I end up with the same results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        ReportDocument loReport = new ReportDocument();

        loReport.Load(path+"InventoryItemsBarCodeLabel.rpt");

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder loConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConnectionUtilities.getConnectionString());

        ParameterValues currentParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
        ParameterDiscreteValue parameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        parameterDiscreteValue.Value = Convert.ToInt32(psMasterId);

        loReport.SetParameterValue("pnMasterId", parameterDiscreteValue.Value);
        loReport.SetDatabaseLogon(loConnectionString.UserID,
            loConnectionString.Password,
            loConnectionString.DataSource,
            loConnectionString.InitialCatalog);
        loReport.Refresh();
        loReport.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 1, 1);
```

Report Parameter: Name: pmMasterId, Type: Number, List of Values: Dynamic, Value = MasterId, Description = MasterId, Parameters = ?pnMasterId

Report Selection Record: {Inventory_Items.MasterId} = {?pnMasterId}

Comment: You've probably already checked your spelling:  "pnMasterId" versus "pnMasterID"

Comment: @SteveWellens - Yes Steve, double checked spelling.

Comment: I even tried changing the Parameter type to a static and listed one of the values I was trying to print as a value.  Still no luck.  I am totally confused by this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to move SetDatabaseLogon() method **before** setting parameters; I believe it resets report document and any params previously passed.

Comment: I tried this as well.  I created the report object, loaded the report, then did the Database login, created the parameters and retried to print.  Same error.

Comment: ok, here is how I set params (I recall similar issue, so I gave up to set them by name rather I set them by index): 

   if (id != null) {
    ParameterDiscreteValue descreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    descreteValue.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(id);
    reportDocument.SetParameterValue(0, descreteValue); //do not refresh if set parameter
   }

and yes, DO NOT call Refresh() is you set params - the report is updated automatically

Comment: This was it.   Not the Parameter type, but calling loReport.Refresh()   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just setting the parameter directly instead of using the Parameter object?

```
loReport.SetParameterValue("pnMasterId", Convert.ToInt32(psMasterId));
```

Comment: Yes!  Tried this as well, no luck.